# Can time travel result in another person?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, time-travel, alternate-worlds, alternate-reality

One of my characters goes back in time (and to an alternate realm) by sixteen years, then returns to her original realm a year **before** she left (so after spending fifteen years in the alternate world), and is now fifteen years older. Are there two of her now? What about after the moment when she goes back in time. Is that person stuck in a time loop?

Comment: There are a ton of ways to solve time travel. Entering the same time but anything you do doesn't change it, as it already happened. Or it changes. Some branch out and others are just similar. Take your pick and have both persons there or not. Put restrictions on interacting or whatever. I personally like people arriving in the same timeline, so there's 2 (or more if you keep travelling to a timeline the original and the travelling you are.)

Comment: This video contains several possibilities for time travel duplication:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3zTfXvYZ9s

Comment: It all depends on how time travel works in the story, doesn't it? Anyway, welcome to WorldBuilding! This site is not a discussion forum; it is a question and answer site, and questions are expected to have *one* objectively correct answer; as written, your question doesn't fit, because time travel works in any way you want it to work, as required by the story. You may want to take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the purpose, the rules and expectations of this site.

Comment: Since your query is in danger of being closed as opinion based, I think you should concentrate on helping us why it is you're not just fishing for opinions. Tell us what this fictional world is like. Obviously there's some kind of magic a/o technology that allows a person to travel not only through time & space but also into other realms of time & space. What is this magic a/o technology like? As written, you might as well toss a coin, because there could be anywhere between 0 and 4 of her left over, or maybe more, or perhaps less, all depending.

Comment: elemtilas and AlexP, thanks for your feedback. I don't really understand why it's opinion based? I thought it was a pretty straightforward worldbuilding question. I just want to know, if someone travels back in time, and to an alternate universe, what would happen to the duplicate person after the original moment in time when the time travel first occurred. A magic wormhole allows the travel through time and space.

Comment: @JoanNord There's no 'factual' answer to the question, as time travel has never been observed in the real universe. (Time travel *back* in time, that is.) Thus, what would actually happen if someone bent the universe is a matter of theory and discussion, and in fiction runs the whole gamut depending on the author's preferences. Does that answer your question as to why this is opinion-based?

Comment: The arguments for closing this question are terribly flawed imo. However, this seems like an easy and obvious question to most people familiar with millions of hours of sci fi entertainment. This has been done so often on tv alone ... which is why it may seem a bit ridiculous to ask. However, just because many have seen time travel shows, this doesn't mean that everybody has to and know all variations out there - in order to ask a question. I hope this gets reopened.

Answer (score 7):

Heinlein got there first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies.

Yes, there are two of her -- there are two bodies that occupy different spaces at the same time. The young one is in the chair by the window, the older one is over by the fireplace.

When the younger one stands up and walks into the time machine, the older one still exists (you have clearly described a non-looped path) so there is no reason for a classic "time loop" paradox.

For a reasonably simple paradox, have the older sabotage her younger self's trip. Or for a more complex mind-bender, have the older *replace* the younger on the trip (there's your loop).

Honestly, Time Travel gets messy, what with all the Terminators popping back from the future to try to bring about the Machine Dystopia.

Comment: "All You Zombies" - perhaps the first SF story to feature a sex change as a major plot element.

Answer (score -2):

This answer will most definitely not help, but I just want to put it out there to help others who look into time travel for their story.

I have a few theories on time travel, none of which I've been able to prove 'cause, well, there's no time travel.

Theory1- changing time changes the event that triggered you changing the event, thereby removing the need to time travel and breaking the universe. (well, maybe not the last part)

Example- You forgot your, say, cell phone, and are on the way to work. There's no time to go back and get it, and you really need to check your phone. So, you pull out your time travel device and go back a few hours. Once back in time, you put your phone in a place you know you will find it. But then this is where it gets tricky- if you have your phone, *then you have no reason to time travel*. because you have your phone and have no need to time travel to get your phone, the universe breaks(or something. who knows what happens when time is messed with?).

Theory2(this one should help answer your question)- traveling back to the point in time when you first traveled back or after is a must.

Example- You go back in time to, IDK, watch that episode of Voltron you missed. After doing that something, you realize you lost your time machine or just don't want to skip ahead because maybe you ate a burrito and time travel makes you throw up. Anyway, if you don't jump back to where you left, *there are two yous*. Doing this over and over again can make tons of yous. Seeing your other yous will probably cause some panic among the general public, but I doubt this one would break the universe. Mr Peabody and Sherman shows this happening towards the end, might be worth watching. If you don't go back to when you left or later, there ends up being two yous. If you don't jump back before the point in time when you left passes, you lose the opportunity to reduce the yous to one, because even going back to try and change it will only make more yous, and jumping back to the point you left will accomplish nothing, and there is destined to be two yous forever.

Doubt that makes sense, let me try again- you go back three hours from 9PM. If you don't jump back *by 9PM*, there ends up being 2 yous, and you can't do anything about that.

Theory3- Going back is safer than going forward

Explanation- Going back in time to observe, and to an extent, change, is safer than observing the future. The future is ever changing, there are infinite many ways the world could go. In two seconds, North Korea could launch nukes across the world, or the business man going up to his office could wait half a second too long and fall to his death due to an elevator failure. The future is never certain, even seeing the future, even if unrelated to you, is likely to change it.

Theory4- The farther back you go, the more impact you will have

If you go back in time, your range of influence increases exponentially the farther back you go. If you end up getting one guy killed for some reason, that one guy could have been the great-great-(several more greats)-grandfather of a lot of people, who would then cease to exist because said grandpa is now dead. So, it's best to observe than change.

TL;DR

Just don't. My head almost breaks when thinking about time travel, and if it were possible, I'd hope that whoever was time traveling knew what they were doing. In your case, read theory2.

EDIT- almost forgot the most important one

Theory5- you can't change the past because it has already happened

You cannot change the past because the past has already happened and any changes have already been made. I'd ad more onto this, but I'm low on time,  I'll add some tomorrow.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's an extemporaneous list of idiosyncratic musings about how time travel may work in various stories. As an essay, it would be greatly improved by citing examples of stories which use time travel rules corresponding to each point. As an answer to an ill-defined question it is not salvageable.

Comment: Re: Theory 2: She has to travel back to before, or my plot doesn't work. To better explain my question, let's say it's 2016. She jumps back 16 years to 2000 & to an alternate realm where she lives for 15 yrs, then goes back to her own realm in 2015, one year before she time traveled. Essentially, she's only traveled back in time, when she comes back to her realm, it's not time travel, it's just from one realm to another. So, my question is: are there two of her (yes, I think so)...but what about after the time in 2016 when she first traveled back. Should one of them have to disappear?

Comment: @JoanNord Yes one of them did disappear. The one who first travelled back in time to another realm, Being two of them is only temporary, & they do have age differences.